# Jquery CSS assigning negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     get_font_size();
     set_sidebar();

});
function get_font_size()
{
var b=$(window).width();
var side_size=b*260/1440;
b=b-side_size;
$("#sidebar").css({"width":side_size});
$("#alexa-widget img").css({"width":side_size});
$(".fb-like-box").attr("data-width",side_size); 
}
function set_sidebar()
{
var b=$(window).width();
var font_size=b*65/1440;
var font_size_2=b*133/1440;
var margin_top=b*10/1440;
margin_top*=-1;
margin_top=Math.round(margin_top);
$("#my_tabs li").css({"font-size":font_size});
$("#header").css({"font-size":font_size_2,"margin-top":margin_top});

}
</script>
```

Everything works fine except the margin-top property.I can't assign margin-top to a negative value.It fails but font size and other properties work's fine.Why jquery css settings fails with negative values?If I do the the same inside css it work's perfect.I need this to alter the webpage according to screen resolutions So I can't do that inside CSS.I need jQuery fix for this.I already have viewport meta tag in my code so please don't suggest viewport or media query solutions.I have checked the margin_top variable with alert(margin_top) and it shows me a correct negative value as desired so the calculation takes place correctly only the css setting part fails.Please help me fix this.Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the margin-top using jQuery, you must add the units (in this case: px) at the end

Example:

```
>>> $("body").css("margin-top");
"0px"
>>> $("body").css("margin-top", "10");
[body]
>>> $("body").css("margin-top");
"0px"
>>> $("body").css("margin-top", "10px");
[body]
>>> $("body").css("margin-top");
"10px"
```

---

**EDIT** (to make it more clear on how to fix your code:

Change the line in your code that looks like:

```
$("#header").css({"font-size":font_size_2,"margin-top":margin_top});
```

to

```
$("#header").css({"font-size":font_size_2,"margin-top":margin_top + "px"});
```

Comment: I need to do that dynamically.The value changes depending on screen resolutions.Let me try it.

Comment: How is it incorrect?  I tried my exact code with negative numbers and it works.  The only reason he can't set the margin to negative numbers is because he is forgetting the units.

Comment: Because it's bad practice to supply values as strings when they're not strings.

Comment: this answer should not be accepted as it is not true.. yes supplying units works, but is not required

Comment: @user1613360  put a demo together in jsfiddle.net that replicates original problem

Comment: @charlietfl The code I have in my first output is straight out of the Firebug console.  Have you even tried to validate what you are saying?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with doing it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qXmfJ/)?

```
$('div').css({marginTop:-100});​
```

Not everything needs to be [stringly typed](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2010/05/09/new-programming-jargon/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a unit of measurement for your margin.

```
$("#header").css({"font-size":font_size_2,"margin-top":margin_top+"%"});
```

Comment: not true, jQuery will automatically set "px" if a number is used

Comment: @charlietfl: I don't think so.If it was true then it should have worked for me but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed using `$("#header").css({"font-size":font_size_2,"margin-top":margin_top+"%"});`.