# How to assign negative value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox with two options in jQuery, withdrawal and deposit. When withdrawal is selected I want to assign negative to amount.The below link shows the image.

[image]

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769060/jquery-css-assigning-negative-values

Comment: @ManishThapa What does CSS have to do with this

Comment: `amount = -1 * $("selector").val();`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us what you have tried so far? What happens when your user types in the amount after the transaction type has been selected?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that by `input` event on `select` *input*

```js
$(function() {
  const selectListEle = $('select');
  selectListEle.on('input', function(e) {
    const selectVal = selectListEle.val();
    const inputVal = $('input').val();
    if (selectVal === 'withdrawal') {
      if (inputVal) {
        $('input').val(-inputVal);
      }
    } else {
      if (inputVal) {
        $('input').val(-inputVal);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>none</option>
  <option>withdrawal</option>
</select>
<input type="number" value="">
```

Comment: `jQuery` is `javascript` by the way so no harm at all to mixing between them  the opposite sometimes you have to use *vanilla javascript*  to achieve complex code implementation such *array manipulating* there's noway in `jQuery` to do that by *jQuery* you have to use *vanilla js*

Comment: That's right, but this can be solved by using jQuery only, it's not necessary to mix native Javascript with jQuery functionalities at this point.

Comment: **whay if twice?** `selectVal === 'withdrawal'` because i want to make sure if the use choose *withdrawal* and if it's only add `negative` -- `inputVal` *constant variable* i would to avoid repetitive code `$('input').val()` -- **what i used?** again i want to make sure only if the *input* has `value` add `negative` with that implementation i strict the behavior to avoid any error may happening

Comment: "*jQuery is javascript by the way so no harm at all to mixing between them*" - **generally** for DOM manipulation it's much better to **be consistent**.  eg don't use `e.target.value` then `$(e.target).val()` - stick to one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for $('input') in the whole DOM is a really bad idea.

Much cleaner:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.selectA').on('input', function(e) {
    var selectedVal = $(e.currentTarget).val(),
      $targetInput = $('.inputA'),
      inputVal = $targetInput.val();
    if (selectedVal === 'withdrawal' && inputVal.length) {
      $targetInput.val(['-', inputVal].join(''));
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectA">
  <option>none</option>
  <option>withdrawal</option>
</select>
<input class="inputA" type="number" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to give your `select` `option`s a value of `1` for `+ve` and `-1` for `-ve`, then you just multiple the two value together.

```
$("#inp").val() * $("#opt").val()
```

```js
function calc() {
  $(this).nextAll("#result").text($("#inp").val() * $("#opt").val());
}
$("#inp").on("input", calc);
$("#opt").on("change", calc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt">
  <option value="1">deposit</option>
  <option value="-1">withdrawal</option>
</select>
<input id="inp" type="number" value="" />
<span id='result'></span>
```